# How to use R for a log-likelihood function with density f being a mixture?

Tags: r, statistics

*Consider the density f arining from a mixture f(x) = πf1(x) + (1 − π)f2(x) where f1 ∼ N(0, 1) and f2 ∼N(μ,1). 
Write an R function for the log-likelihood function of the parameter (π, μ) that takes as input a vector of observations x from f*

I know that to incorporate f(x) into the log function, you use the dnorm function to get f1 and f2.

```
f1 = dnorm(x, 0, 1)
f2 = dnorm(x, u, 1)
```

and then we would do

```
LL=sum(log(f(x))
```

But overall I am unsure how to actually execute this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can find the helpful information from here https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/intro_to_em.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/intro_to_em.html, I guess you might have already know how to construct the log-likelihood function.

Below is an example that might work for your goal

```
f <- function(X,p,u) sum(log(p*dnorm(X,0,1) + (1-p)*dnorm(X,u,1)))
```